# Issue with making a controller method asynchronous with Spring 3.2.RC2

Tags: spring-mvc, asynchronous, controller

I am trying to test the **latest asynchronous feature of Spring MVC controllers** but I have not been able to get it to work.

Here is the code for my async method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public Callable<String> async(final Model model) {
        System.out.println("entered async controller method");
        return new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(2000L);
                model.addAttribute("message", "asyncRequest dealt with");
                System.out.println("about to return from call()");
                return "hello";
            }
        };
}
```

Here is the relevant portion from web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

However **"about to return from call()"** is never printed in the console and I never get to see such logs as this: **08:25:17 [MvcAsync1] WebAsyncManager** - ...
in the console...

FYI, I use Spring 3.2.RC2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found why my sample was not working: one has to add the following to the web-mvc configuration file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:async-support default-timeout="3000"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Silly question of mine but haven't found any resource yet: is the timeout in millis or in seconds? From your code I guess millis...

Answer (score 6):

To further configure the `async-support` implement a `AsyncTaskExecutor`

> By default Spring MVC uses a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` to execute Callable instances returned by controller methods. For production you must replace it with an `AsyncTaskExecutor` implementation configured appropriately for your environment.

Create the AsyncTaskExecutor

```
<beans:bean id="asyncTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <beans:property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <beans:property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</beans:bean>
```

Then assign the `task-executor`

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
    <mvc:async-support default-timeout="30000" task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor" />
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/10/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-making-a-controller-method-asynchronous/

Answer (score 0):

Hi doing a similar application with the following code :

```
public String doSlowWork() {

     System.out.println("Start  slow work");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("finish slow work");

    return "index";       // return view's name
  }
```

returning index but not giving the log info of the method